# AnimationDrawable to draw on canvas

Tags: android, animation, android-canvas

I have a `View`, on which I have drawn a checker board

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i ++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j ++) {
        float x = j * width;
        float y = i * height;
        if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
            canvas.drawRect(x, y, x + width, y + height, lite_square);
        }
```

Now, I want to place an `DrawableAnimation` object at any random square in the checker board. I need any help/ pointers for solution.

Comment: use http://jsfiddle.net for demo.

Comment: @KarSho jsFiddle is able to run android code?!

Comment: i don't know correctly. but, you can test animation option.